# Function result as enumerated type - how to proof all of variants are in case section

Tags: delphi, pascal

I have a enumerated type for some function result classification, and some case switch for controlling of function result.

How can I be sure - all of possible function result are covered in my case?

Example

```
type T_Function_Results = ( fr_None, fr_Ok, fr_Fail, fr_Unknown );

function Foo : T_Function_Results;
begin
  // something ..
  Result := fr_Unknown;
end;

begin
   case Foo of
     fr_None : ;
     fr_Ok : ;
     fr_Fail : ;
     else : {I can use else, but it's not clear and runtime only } ;
    end;
end.
```

In this example `fr_Unknown` result **is not covered** in `case`, and it's hard to see it. In ideal, I want a some compiler warning here.

Comment: With the `else` block included, all possible cases are covered, at compile time. It's up to you to write the code to handle them. You can be sure because the [language specification](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Case_Statements) says so. In other words, if you encounter a case where a value "slips through" a case statement which includes an `else` block, you've found a compiler bug.

Comment: Some languages actually can enforce that you must write a different section in your case to handle every branch.  OCAML comes to mind as one that can. Haskell is another.  Pascal is not such a language, at least not with the case.  You could use Interfaces and make each of the cases be a method which you call.   Then if you add a new case, the compilation would stop on any implementer who did not implement the new interface method. Updating the Interface to contain a method that has the same name as the elements in your enum is left as an exercise for you.

Comment: And it would only work with range checking on anyway, since otherwise undefined values could enter the enum. Probably the other languages have a tighter rein on that too.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get the compiler to issue a warning or an error in this case. The reason being is that it is perfectly valid for you to write code that chooses not to handle all of the enumeration's values. If the compiler were to issue a warning then it would be triggered by large amounts of perfectly valid code.

You can certainly arrange for your code to fail a runtime if it fails to handle one of the values. For instance:

```
case Foo of
fr_None:
  ;
fr_Ok:
  ;
fr_Fail:
  ;
else
  raise EAssertionFailed.Create(...);
end;
```

I personally use this helper function:

```
procedure RaiseAssertionFailed;
begin
  raise EAssertionFailed.CreateFmt(
    'A critical error has occurred:' + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + 'Assertion failed at %p.',
    [ReturnAddress]
  ) at ReturnAddress;
end;
```

which would be used like so:

```
case Foo of
....
else
  RaiseAssertionFailed;
end;
```

If the job of your case statement is to assign to a local variable, or a result variable then the compiler might warn about uninitialized variables. For instance:

```
var
  i: Integer;
....
case Foo of
fr_None:
  i := 0;
fr_Ok:
  i := 42;
fr_Fail:
  i := 666;
end;
Bar(i);
```

Comment: I think David's route it the way to go...then write a Test Case with Dunit/DUnitX to test all the enumerated types are covered.  If someone slips a new enumerated type it will fail the test.

Answer (score 4):

I've used this a few times:

```
begin
   case Foo of
     fr_None : ;
     fr_Ok : ;
     fr_Fail : ;
   end;
  {$IF High(T_Function_Results) <> fr_Fail} Something Changed {$IFEND}  
end.
```

Comment: If you are going to do this, use `{$MESSAGE Fatal 'your message goes here'}`  What you have written is not much use at all though. You could add a new value in the middle of the enum, something that is frequently done. This gives you a false sense of security.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I be sure - all of possible function result are covered in my case?

You cannot: that's why developers do exist. The IDE cannot warn you about code which is not at its best but is syntactically correct.

In a case like this you may consider to throw an exception at runtime when no declared case is matched.

```
case Foo of
  fr_None: ;
  fr_Ok: ;
  fr_Fail: ;
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Not implemented');
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I be sure - all of possible function result are covered in my case?
>   If compiler can't warn about it then consider using static analysis tools.

RAD Studio has built-in QA Audits functionality that has the rule for check you are looking for.

> **Enumeration Constant is Not Handled in switch statement (ECNHS)** 
>   Description:
>
> The compiler does not produce an error or warning when not all of the
>   enumeration constants are handled in a switch statement and no default
>   branch is provided. Although in many situations it is desired
>   behavior, it can also be programmer error; therefore, ECNHS produces
>   error messages in these cases. To eliminate this message and to
>   clarify your code, add the explicit default branch.

The availability of this feature depends on RAD Studio edition. QA Audits functionality is very limited in Delphi Professional edition, and does not allow to use above-mentioned check. But if you have Enterprise+ edition it might be the way to go.

Additionally you might consider to check 3d party static code analyzers (not free) like FixInsight, Peganza Pascal Analyzer, CodeHealer.